# My for loops within my csv writerows are not placing my "titles" and "dates" side-by-side

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, writer

I'm trying to output the "titles" and "dates" of each article row by row that I scraped from a specific area from a webpage to csv.

So I have it that:

```
with open("Output.csv", "a") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
```

...

```
        wr.writerows([[title.text.strip()] for title in specific_area.findAll('h1')] + [[date.text.strip()] for date in specific_area.findAll('h6')])
```

This output just does the for loop for the titles first, and then does the for loop for the dates after, so each is in their own row.

How can I have it that the for loops are done simultaneously? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide your output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `zip` function.

`wr.writerows([[title.text.strip(), date.text.strip()] for title, date in zip(specific_area.findAll('h1'), specific_area.findAll('h6'))])`